# STM32CubeIDE HAL - Generated EXTI interrupts won't trigger - STM32F4

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I've created (so far) simple project for STM32F411 MCU in STM32CubeIDE.
When using the GUI configurator to enable hardware interrupt EXTI for my pins (originally I wanted to use PB5, but added PB8 as it's just sticking out on my PCB and PA0, as it has button attached between it and ground) it generates configuration code to my main.cpp (for generation I rename it to main.c so configurator sees it), it created proper event handlers to which I added method `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback`, according to instructions in `stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c`, however, interrupts are not fired. Breakpoints are not hit, no output on serial.

I've set those pins to use EXTI, set their respective pull-ups/pull-downs etc. according to my needs (although tried to change it with no effect).
I've enabled those interrupts (EXTI line0 and EXTI line[9:5]) in NVIC page, followed countless tutorials on the issue (e.g. this one: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/STM32CubeMX_Tutorial_Series:_EXTI, also official ST Electronics youtube channel).

My board is STM32F411CEU based chinese Black Pill.
Full code can be seen here: https://github.com/domints/LoadCellCWManipulator (latest commit, for future reference `f4330cd6066f227f5cf3d3ea619adcc810025b72`).

Might there be something I am missing? All other code I've tried so far works without a problem.
Might be that CubeIDE is missing something during generation and I need to write something by hand?

I'm trying to use C++ (although IDE supposedly has that options it makes it harder), as I am coming from higher level background.

Comment: Library code is C, main is C++, so `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` should be declared as `extern "C"`. Without it, a weak stub from library is called from interrupt

Comment: @Flexz, I'll try that, thanks, although what worries me is that beakpoints put in `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler` and `EXTI0_IRQHandler` methods of `stm32f4xx_it.c` don't fire either, and code put in beetween comments `USER CODE BEGIN EXTI9_5_IRQn 1` isn't running as well :(

EDIT: I've added those externs to `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` and it even stopped at breakpoints in `stm32f4xx_it.c`... Weird...

Comment: @Flexz I removed those externs now, and it still works. Yesterday I tried everything, including rebooting PC, reconnecting both ST-Link and Blue Pill, with no success. 
Today I started my day with creating this question and now, even though everything stayed running and connected for the whole night, for some reason it works. 

Is it this the normal way you work with STMs? Is that something you just have to get used to?

EDIT: One thing I recollect I might've done today and not yesterday - to cleanup for git I removed Debug folder...

Comment: I've reviewed `stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.h` file and `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` has a prototype declared there, with `extern "C"`. So specifying it in your source file isn't required if the header is included directly or indirectly. STMs rarely gives weird problems, and their libraries may be ugly, but not bugged. Your problem might be related to renaming main.c to main.cpp and back, this could break build system somehow - that's why cleaning old built files helped.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGippity had this answer which worked for me:

When using C++ with STM32CubeIDE and STM32 HAL libraries, you typically need to declare interrupt callback functions with extern "C" to ensure proper linkage. This is because C++ uses name mangling, which can result in different symbol names for functions declared in C++ compared to those declared in C.

To declare an interrupt callback function in C++ with extern "C", you would do something like this:

```
extern "C" {
    void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
        // Your callback implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the question, STM's HAL doesn't need it, because it's defining function with prototype declaring already having `extern "C"`.
Comments also mentioned, that after clearing the build output code worked without the `extern` clause, but I am not even surprised that ChatGPT generated unrelated answer...